# Error in my Airflow pipeline when it run Spark job

Tags: pyspark, airflow, spark-submit

I have error when my airflow pipeline run a job on my local Spark. My application contains two files:

**dag-airflow-spark-submitop.py :**

```
import airflow
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.spark_submit_operator import SparkSubmitOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'moi',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=30),
    'start_date': datetime(year=2023, month=7, day=9),
}

with airflow.DAG('dag_teste_spark_connection', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='0 1 * * *') as dag:
    task_elt_documento_pagar = SparkSubmitOperator(
        task_id='task_run_pysparkjob',
        conn_id='spark',
        application="./dags/sparkjob.py",
    )
```

**sparkjob.py :**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("test") \
    .getOrCreate()

data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()
```

When I run my DAG I get this error:

```
*** Found local files:
    ***   * /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=dag_teste_spark_connection/run_id=manual__2023-07-09T14:53:27.424066+00:00/task_id=task_run_pysparkjob/attempt=1.log
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=non-requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: dag_teste_spark_connection.task_run_pysparkjob manual__2023-07-09T14:53:27.424066+00:00 [queued]>
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: dag_teste_spark_connection.task_run_pysparkjob manual__2023-07-09T14:53:27.424066+00:00 [queued]>
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1308} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 6
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1327} INFO - Executing <Task(SparkSubmitOperator): task_run_pysparkjob> on 2023-07-09 14:53:27.424066+00:00
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:57} INFO - Started process 278 to run task
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:84} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'dag_teste_spark_connection', 'task_run_pysparkjob', 'manual__2023-07-09T14:53:27.424066+00:00', '--job-id', '98', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/dag-***-spark-submitop.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpuzlf2_yf']
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:85} INFO - Job 98: Subtask task_run_pysparkjob
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {task_command.py:410} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: dag_teste_spark_connection.task_run_pysparkjob manual__2023-07-09T14:53:27.424066+00:00 [running]> on host ef29c1050b71
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1547} INFO - Exporting env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='moi' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='dag_teste_spark_connection' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='task_run_pysparkjob' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2023-07-09T14:53:27.424066+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='1' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='manual__2023-07-09T14:53:27.424066+00:00'
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'spark' for task execution.
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:37 UTC] {spark_submit.py:339} INFO - Spark-Submit cmd: spark-submit --master spark://MacBook-Pro-de-AdminSensei-9.local:7077:7077 --name arrow-spark ./dags/sparkjob.py
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - /home/***/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 68: ps: command not found
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:490} INFO - JAVA_HOME is not set
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1824} ERROR - Task failed with exception
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/operators/spark_submit.py", line 157, in execute
        self._hook.submit(self._application)
      File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py", line 422, in submit
        f"Cannot execute: {self._mask_cmd(spark_submit_cmd)}. Error code is: {returncode}."
    airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot execute: spark-submit --master spark://MacBook-Pro-de-AdminSensei-9.local:7077:7077 --name arrow-spark ./dags/sparkjob.py. Error code is: 1.
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1350} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=dag_teste_spark_connection, task_id=task_run_pysparkjob, execution_date=20230709T145327, start_date=20230709T145337, end_date=20230709T145338
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:38 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:109} ERROR - Failed to execute job 98 for task task_run_pysparkjob (Cannot execute: spark-submit --master spark://MacBook-Pro-de-AdminSensei-9.local:7077:7077 --name arrow-spark ./dags/sparkjob.py. Error code is: 1.; 278)
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:38 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:225} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
    [2023-07-09, 14:53:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2651} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Can you help me to resolve it please ?

Answer (score 0):

From your error, you might have an issue with your environment setup.  Can you check if all env variables have been set, like $SPARK_HOME. You also need to make sure the versions of Spark and Java are compatible with each other.

Comment: Since I'm able to start the spark master and worker and I'm able to launch a pyspark job with the spark-submit command, I don't understand how my environment can be misconfigured.
The command echo $JAVA_HOME sends me this :
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-11.jdk/Contents/Home
and echo $SPARK_HOME this :
/Users/my_name/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3